# Can clone using different Git GUI Clients but failed authentication on GithubDesktop

Tags: git, github, cloning

When I try to clone our repository, I'm always getting

> We were unable to authenticate with "our repo" Please enter your username and password to try again

I have correct credentials, but I can't clone our repo using GitHub Desktop (which I want to use)

I was able to clone using GitKraken, GitBash, and SourceTree but not on GitHub Desktop.

I tried following the answer here [Github Desktop Authentication Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707910/github-desktop-authentication-failed)
but it still didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check first, if your are on Windows, if you have credentials stored in the Windows Credential Manager for github.com, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39592537/6309).

By removing them, the next push from GitHub Desktop should prompt you to enter those credentials again. See then if the issue persists.

Comment: hmm I can't even clone the repository, I have credentials stored for github when I try to remove it, still the same..

Comment: as specified in the description, "I was able to clone using GitKraken, GitBash, and SourceTree but not on GitHub Desktop"

Comment: @JCBorlagdan Right so the GitHub Desktop client must cache its credentials elsewhere...